# How to use STOMP in kotlin?

Tags: spring, kotlin, stomp, spring-websocket

First, I'm so sorry about my English.

I'a Kotlin beginner.
Then, I want to make STOMP Chat API with Kotlin.
Simple Api, but I can't make it.. and I don't know why.

The system I think is
User (session) can make chatRoom,
and User can subscribe chatRoom.
Server can send messages to chatRoom(sbuscribe).

- no lombok
- MariaDB, JPA

My package is
chat

- controller

  - ChatController.kt
  - RoomChatController.kt
- dto

  - ChatMessageDTO.kt
  - ChatRoomDTO.kt
- repository

  - ChatRoomRepository.kt
- service

  - ChatRoomService.kt
    config
- WebSocketConfig.kt

WebSocketConfig.kt

```
package com.example.stompserver.config

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
class WebSocketConfig: WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    override fun registerStompEndpoints(registry: StompEndpointRegistry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").withSockJS()
    }

    override fun configureMessageBroker(config: MessageBrokerRegistry) {
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/pub")
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/sub")
    }
}
```

ChatMessageDTO.kt

```
package com.example.stompserver.chat.dto

class ChatMessageDTO {
    var roomId: String = ""
    var writer: String = ""
    var message: String = ""
}
```

ChatRoomDTO.kt

```
package com.example.stompserver.chat.dto

import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketSession
import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.HashSet


class ChatRoomDTO {
    var roomId: String = ""
    var name: String = ""
    var sessions: Set<WebSocketSession> = HashSet()

    fun create(
        name: String
        ): ChatRoomDTO {
        val room: ChatRoomDTO = ChatRoomDTO()
        room.roomId = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        room.name = name
        return room
    }

}
```

ChatRoomRepository.kt

```
package com.example.stompserver.chat.repository

import com.example.stompserver.chat.dto.ChatRoomDTO
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository

interface ChatRoomRepository: JpaRepository<ChatRoomDTO, String> {
}
```

ChatRoomService.kt

```
package com.example.stompserver.chat.service

import com.example.stompserver.chat.dto.ChatRoomDTO
import com.example.stompserver.chat.repository.ChatRoomRepository
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service

@Service
class ChatRoomService(
    private val chatRoomRepository: ChatRoomRepository
) {

    fun findAllRooms(): List<ChatRoomDTO> {
        return this.chatRoomRepository.findAll()
    }

    fun createChatRoomDTO(name: String): ChatRoomDTO {
        val room: ChatRoomDTO = ChatRoomDTO().create(name)
        this.chatRoomRepository.save(room)
        return room
    }
}
```

ChatController.kt

```
package com.example.stompserver.chat.controller

import com.example.stompserver.chat.dto.ChatMessageDTO
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.MessageMapping
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Payload
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

@RestController
class ChatController(
    val template: SimpMessagingTemplate
) {

    @MessageMapping("/chat/enter")
    fun enter(@Payload message: ChatMessageDTO) {
        message.apply {
            message.message = "${message.writer} enter"
            template.convertAndSend("/sub/chat/room/" + message.roomId, message)
        }
    }

    @MessageMapping("/chat/message")
    fun message(@Payload message: ChatMessageDTO) {
        template.convertAndSend("/sub/chat/room/" + message.roomId, message)
    }
}
```

RoomController.kt

```
package com.example.stompserver.chat.controller

import com.example.stompserver.chat.service.ChatRoomService
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/chat")
class RoomController(
    val chatRoomService: ChatRoomService
) {
    @GetMapping("/rooms")
    fun rooms(): ModelAndView? {
        val mv = ModelAndView("/chat/rooms")
        mv.addObject("list", chatRoomService.findAllRooms())
        return mv
    }

    fun create(
        @RequestParam name: String, rttr: RedirectAttributes
    ): String {
        rttr.addFlashAttribute("roomName", chatRoomService.createChatRoomDTO(name))
        return "redirect:/chat/rooms"
    }
}
```

and I got error

> 2021-09-17 13:19:13.338 ERROR 10140 --- [  restartedMain]
> o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'roomController' defined in file
> [C:\Workspace\stomp-server\target\classes\com\example\stompserver\chat\controller\RoomController.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'chatRoomService' defined in file
> [C:\Workspace\stomp-server\target\classes\com\example\stompserver\chat\service\ChatRoomService.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'chatRoomRepository' defined in
> com.example.stompserver.chat.repository.ChatRoomRepository defined in
> @EnableJpaRepositories declared on
> JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration:
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class
> com.example.stompserver.chat.dto.ChatRoomDTO

How can I fix this, and please tell me any other problems TT

- How can I send message by server to client? I use postman with Json but I get 500 error

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to root error

```
Not a managed type: class com.example.stompserver.chat.dto.ChatRoomDTO
```

you must either put `@Entity` annotation to your `ChatRoomDTO` or use different class as `ChatRoomRepository` generic type parameter

Comment: Thank you so much! I cant start server now!
But I got a issue! I can sue sessions(ChatRoomDTO) anymore, but is not problem?